# Acessar a imagem de upload em codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fiz uma função seguindo (copiado) a documentação do codeigniter 4 e esta funcionando belezinha. Problema que não consigo acessar as imagens do upload na pasta writable que ele envia.

`class Upload extends BaseController
{
protected $helpers = ['form'];

```
public function index()
{
    return view('upload_form', ['errors' => []]);
}

public function upload()
{
    $validationRule = [
        'userfile' => [
            'label' => 'Image File',
            'rules' => [
                'uploaded[userfile]',
                'is_image[userfile]',
                'mime_in[userfile,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,image/webp]',
                'max_size[userfile,100]',
                'max_dims[userfile,1024,768]',
            ],
        ],
    ];
    if (! $this->validate($validationRule)) {
        $data = ['errors' => $this->validator->getErrors()];

        return view('upload_form', $data);
    }

    $img = $this->request->getFile('userfile');

    if (! $img->hasMoved()) {
        $filepath = WRITEPATH . 'uploads/' . $img->store();

        $data = ['uploaded_fileinfo' => new File($filepath)];

        return view('upload_success', $data);
    }

    $data = ['errors' => 'The file has already been moved.'];

    return view('upload_form', $data);
}
```

}`

Como faço para acessar estas imagens? quando tento acessar pelo endereço ele informa não ter permissão

Tentei alterar esta linha na esperança que fosse para outra pasta mesmo assim não funcionou

`$filepath = WRITEPATH . 'uploads/' . $img->store();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você ta usando a estrutura padrão?
se sim, você pode observar que a pasta qual está tentando acessar não fica publica.

- **Nesse caso você tem que mover o arquivo para a pasta publica.**
- Caso você queira criar arquivos privados para apenas logados tem que implementar uma função por rota.

  $filepath = WRITEPATH . 'uploads/';

  $img->store("../../" . $filepath, $img->getRandomName());

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz em pode ajudar!